# adobe air Google play services integration error

Tags: air, google-play-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyUty.jpg)

Google play services not working in adobe air. It fails with the message given in screenshot. Will it be any configuration issue in developer console?

Comment: As the event says it can't log in because the licence check have failed. AFAIK you need to login on your device with the same account that you use to login to the Google Play Developer Console as your primary device account. Then you can test your Google Play stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services/issues/2), adding "air." before the package name at Google Developer can solve the problem. Try also to upload an (test) APK to the Google Developer Console in order to test Google Play Services.

Check this [tutorial from GitHub](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services).